# Typescript KeyOf - Array or Object - Desperate

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

I have the following class.....

```
export class Person<T, C = T> {
    lens: any = null;
    private value: T;

    constructor(value: T, newLens?: any) {
        this.value = value;
        this.lens = newLens;
    }

    at<K extends keyof C>(path: keyof C): Person<T, C[K]> {
        if(!this.lens) {
            return new Person<T, C[K]>(this.value, Lens.lens(path));
        }
        return new Person<T, C[K]>(this.value, Lens.compose(this.lens)(Lens.lens(path)));
    }

    get(): any {
        if(!this.lens) return this.value;
        return Lens.get(this.lens)(this.value);
    }

    set(f: (newValue: any) => any): T {
        return Lens.set(this.lens)(f(this.get()))(this.value);
    }
}
```

my problem is that when i try and use my new Person class on an object i get the incorrect behaviour.....

```
const TestPerson = {
      name: {
          name: "steve"
      },
      siblings: [{name: "shanon"}]
      age: Infinity
}

const test = new Person(TestPerson).at("name").at("name") // works....
const test2 = new Person(TestPerson).at("siblings").at(0) // fails
const test3 = new Person(TestPerson).at(siblings").at("0") // still fails.
const test4 = new Person(TestPerson).at("nonexistantproperty") //correctly fails.
```

my problem is that i need a "AT" function that can handle keyof objects and keyof arrays, but it seems like no matter how i rework it i can't achieve this.

to me this seems like a massive flaw with typescript, both arrays and objects are just objects under the hood so keyof on an object type and keyof on a array type should work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to wait until typescript 2.9 (in [RC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/16/announcing-typescript-2-9-rc/) at the time of writing, should be released soon). Prior to 2.9 `keyof` only returned string indexes, in 2.9 this will include numeric and symbol keys. See the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592). In 2.9 your code will work as expected without any change.

In 2.8 you can use conditional types to achieve a similar effect

```
type CReturn<C, K extends keyof C> = C extends Array<any> ? C[number] : C[K];
export class Person<T, C = T> {
    lens: any = null;
    private value: T;

    constructor(value: T, newLens?: any) {
        this.value = value;
        this.lens = newLens;
    }

    at<K extends keyof C>(path: C extends Array<any> ? number : K): Person<T, CReturn<C, K>> {
        if(!this.lens) {
            return new Person<T, CReturn<C, K>>(this.value, Lens.lens(path));
        }
        return new Person<T, CReturn<C, K>>(this.value, Lens.compose(this.lens)(Lens.lens(path)));
    }
}
const TestPerson = {
    name: {
        name: "steve"
    },
    siblings: [{ name: "shanon" }],
    age: Infinity
}

const test = new Person(TestPerson).at("name").at("name") // works....
const test2 = new Person(TestPerson).at("siblings").at(0) // ok
const test21 = new Person(TestPerson).at("siblings").at(0).at("name") //ok
const test4 = new Person(TestPerson).at("nonexistantproperty") //correctly fails.
```

Comment: Running through the test cases now but looks like this works, literally spent 4-5 hrs trying to type this thank you so much. i'll probably comment if one of my test cases fail soon though

Comment: You're the man, legit thank you so much everything compiled becides some Omit and Diff errors that came from styled-component.d.ts from swapping to 2.9